# Difference in SAS PROC MIXED between DF when using type VC vs FA0(1) for one random effect model

Tags: mixed-model, sas, degrees-of-freedom

I don't understand why the degrees of freedom (`DF`) are different between `TYPE=VC` and `TYPE=FA0(1)` in case of a one-random effect mixed model. For example:

$$level_{ij} = \mu + \beta_1time + \gamma_i + \varepsilon_{ij}$$

where $\gamma\sim N(0,\sigma^2_\gamma)$ is the random intercept term, and $i$ the batch. The corresponding SAS code:

```
PROC MIXED DATA=data METHOD=REML;
           CLASS batch;
           MODEL level=time / DDFM=SAT ALPHAP=0.10 OUTP=out_p;
           RANDOM int / SUBJECT=batch TYPE=FA0(1);
RUN;
```

The output `out_p` will contain a column `DF` representing the degrees of freedom.

When one runs the above code, but with `TYPE=VC`, the `DF` will be different (while everything else will be the same: model parameter estimates, BLUP and its variance). But I don't believe `DF` should be different since essentially the parameter factorisation of the above model is the same under both `VC` and `FA0(1)`.

Why do I think `DF` should be the same? Because `VC` estimates $\sigma_\gamma$ of the random effect variance matrix $G=[\sigma^2_\gamma]$. The `FA0(1)` will Cholesky-decompose the $G$ matrix, resulting in $G=[\sigma^2_\gamma]=[\lambda][\lambda]$ where the parameter $\lambda$ is mathematically equivalent to $\sigma_\gamma$.

Subsequently the `DF` will be computed based on formula given in [SAS PROC MIXED 14.1, p6090](https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/stat/141/mixed.pdf):

$$DF=\frac{2[l\hat{C}l']^2}{g'Ag}$$

Note that this formula is incomplete. The $l\hat{C}l'$ should be $\text{VAR}(w-\hat{w})$ where $w$ is the predictand, in line with [Henderson (1984), Chapter 5, Eq.29](https://www.ancp.org.br/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Livro-Applications-of-Linear-Models-in-Animal-Breeding.pdf). This also means that $g$ is the gradient of $\text{VAR}(w-\hat{w})$. With these corrections, I can confirm getting the same `DF`-results as SAS for `VC` and `UN` using a handmade-made calculation. But I fail to understand where the difference in `DF` comes from when using `FA0(1)`.

Note also that the difference in `DF` (sometimes differing by 10, hence cannot be due to rounding issues) is clear on specific datasets that I cannot share at this point. On other datasets, there is no difference (as expected).

***Has anyone a clue what may be the cause? I rather think I am overseeing something, than calling it a SAS bug.***